# Json data insert into table in snowflake

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

1
[["id=13456,state=closed]"]

2
[["id=34566,state=closed]",["id=34567,state=open]" ]

create table Staff_status
(id int,
status ?
)
what should be the data type for status and want output in json format, How can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for this function? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html

Comment: Don't change questions to completely new questions.

Comment: please elaborate more on the question, if it is still unresolved

Answer (score 1):

The type of the column is `variant` thus

```
create table student_color (id int, name string, color_code variant);
```

Nick’s point is valid to get your json looking text/string into a variant you need to use PARSE_JSON.

If you want to insert 1 value:

```
insert into student_color 
    select 
        10, 
        'bob the builder', 
        parse_json('[ { color: "red", value: "#f00" }, { color: "green", value: "#0f0" }, { color: "blue", value: "#00f" } ]');
```

If you want to insert many values:

```
insert into student_color 
    select column1, column2, parse_json(column3)
    from values
    (10, 'bob the builder', '[ { color: "red", value: "#f00" }, { color: "green", value: "#0f0" }, { color: "blue", value: "#00f" } ]'),
    (11, 'thomas the tank engine', '[ { color: "red", value: "#f00" }, { color: "green", value: "#0f0" }, { color: "blue", value: "#00f" } ]');
```

### Because you fully changed the question:

the new data you have is not JSON

`[["id=13456,state=closed]"]`
`[["id=34566,state=closed]",["id=34567,state=open]" ]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PARSE_JSON function